# Do Azure Batch jobs need a watcher process?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

We have a very long running operation (potentially days) that we would like to have triggered from a BLOB file written to a Azure Storage. This job could be started once year, never, or many times over a few days.

[Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-technical-overview) jobs look exactly like what we need assuming there doesn't need to be a 'watcher' process on the batch job as it runs. For example, if we can have a Azure Function catch the BLOB event, fire up a Batch job, start the job in a "fire and forget" type fashion, and then the Function ends it is exactly what we need. We aren't really too worried about reporting progress of the job (we are using a SQL table for that), we just want to start the job then monitor it out of band.

Is there a way to start a batch job and let the instigator process disappear while the job continues to run in the background? If not, is there any way to do this without having to have a constantly running process (Worker Role or Fabric Worker)? We are trying to avoid having a process (Worker/Fabric Role, Function using the App Function Plan, etc.) running all the time when 99.9% of the time it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you don't need a watcher process.

Azure Batch tasks are asynchronous in nature. When you add a task (under a job), your call against the Batch service immediately returns with success or failure of the submission action itself (and not if the task completed successfully on a compute node or not). The Batch service takes care of scheduling the task among the available compute nodes in your pool, internally monitoring the progress of the task, updating stats, etc.

If you elect to do so, you can monitor the progress of your task independently of the submitting actor using any SDK, REST API or client tool. Or you can opt to monitor it out-of-band yourself as you have described if your task is updating an external monitor or data store. Or you can schedule a task and not monitor it, the service does not force you to monitor/watch the task.

Comment: You can also enable autoscaling formula which shuts down unused nodes when no one is watching ;)